# How to set-up email notification so that the BPE and BPO receive an email when a user story is moved to complete - DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, notifications, settings, devops

I was hoping someone could help out with a DevOps email notification set-up.

**Goal**: I want to create a notification so that the BPE and BPO receive an email as soon as the DevTeam moves a user story to Completed. In the settings (picture below) I've set Completed equal to 4 Completed.

[image]

**Ask**: I tried the following settings, but when I move a user story to 4 Completed in boards both the BPE and BPO do not receive any email. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Kind regards,

Rutger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set-up email notification so that the BPE and BPO receive an email when a user story is moved to complete - DevOps

You need to ensure that the members of the `BPE` and `BPO` groups are a role in Deliver to Roles：

[image]

And if the BPE and BPO members are not one of the predefined roles, then you can use a custom mailbox:

[image]

Or you could set the [global delivery settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops#manage-global-delivery-settings).